# Error when creating new project with Angular-CLI 6.1.2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I tried creating a new Angular project using `ng new angular-6-boilerplate` but I can't do it anymore with angular-cli latest version. I'm using terminal for windows to create my project but I got this error.

> Schematic input does not validate against the Schema:
>   {"name":"angular-6-boilerplate","version":"6.1.2","newProjectRoot":"projects","skipInstall":false,"linkCli":false,"skipGit":false,"commit":null}
>   Errors:
>
> ```
>   Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector".
> ```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do not include project name special characters or numbers. Try the following:

```
$ ng new angular-boilerplate
```

I did some research & found out that this comes from the schema responsible of creating new Angular applications **[Link Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/1a255e6e4ea5ff85c8c40ca6ca505544761a3289/packages/schematics/angular/workspace/schema.json#L9)**

Comment: yes, thank you. I did't know I wasn't allowed to use numbers when creating a new angular project in angular-cli 6.1.2. It was allowed in earlier versions though.

Comment: You can still use numbers, just not lone numbers.

Answer (score 15):

**No Snakecase**.

> Watch out for underscores as well (not just lone numbers).

```
ng new my_fantastic_app
```

Is an invalid name.

And of course as other people have already say , be careful for 
Lone numbers between dashes

Comment: Well I'm not using underscore and dashes works fine.

Comment: I spent 1 hour the other day , before I realize that I was using underscores. :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for sharing the info man but we should edit your answer a bit. This would be helpful for others that will encounter this error with Angular 6.

Comment: Yes thank you Sherwin , it looks better now.I post this answer because a lot of guys like me writing c and c++ , have the habbit to give snakecase names in files , functions , project etc.

Answer (score 7):

Melchia is correct.

But to be more specific, the problem is the lone number between the dashes.

This will also work:

```
ng new angular6-boilerplate
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know this could work too

Answer (score 2):

Don't use _ (underscore) sign, 
use minus - (minus) sign.

For Example:

Wrong code:

> ng new naytiv_admin_fe

Right code:

> ng new naytiv-admin-fe

Answer (score 1):

Do not include any special characters. You can use the hyphen ( - ) instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

Number at the end also does not work.

I had to change from

> ng new Chapter-4

to

> ng new Chapter4

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid numbers and special characters while giving name of new project of angular.
**ng new angular-6-boilerplate**
Changed to --> **ng new angulaBoilerplate**

Comment: Actually Angular encourages to add dashes, see their [setup guide](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#create-a-workspace-and-initial-application). Also in general it is possible to use numbers, expect for some special cases. So this answer is quite inaccurate.

Comment: Adding dashes never worked for me.

Comment: I use dashes all the time and they work for me in 95% of the cases.