# Angular: ng new error when I create an angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have this error using **ng new project_name:**

**An invalid configuration file was found ['angular.json']. Please delete the file before running the command.**

I am getting this error I don't know how to get the solution.

I uninstalled @angular/cli and installed again

npm clean cache doesnt work too (I dont know if it is problem of my npm version

```
npm version is 6.4.1    
node version is 8.11.1
```

what do i need to solve the problem?

Comment: The error means what it says. Are you certain that there's no angular.json in current or parent directory?

Comment: after this command `ng new project_name` did you `cd  project_name` before starting npm??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using the terminal of IntelliJ IDEA while there is a angular project already imported in the IDEA, it is the problem of the IDEA.So, open the command promt of your windows and create the project.

I did this and I was able to create the project.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be the `_` in `project_name` resulting in the following error:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"project_name","version":"6.0.1","newProjectRoot":"projects","skipInstall":false,"linkCli":false,"skipGit":false,"commit":null}
Errors:

  Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector".
```

Replace `_` e.g. with `-`.

Further readings:

- [Error when creating new project with Angular-CLI 6.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690402/error-when-creating-new-project-with-angular-cli-6-1-2/51752857)
- [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#separate-file-names-with-dots-and-dashes)

Comment: ng new cvfrontend: I had the same problem, anyway I could created in the past names with underscot character. What do you need to show you my configuration?

Comment: What does `ng -v` say? Does `ng new foo && cd foo && npm i && npm start` work?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the working directory in IntelliJ's Karma task, to the Angular project's main directory, also fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the file in c:\users\XXX\.angular.json and it was running ok.

Answer (score 0):

Run following if file is hidden. Open Terminal, run `mv /Users/shivammishra/.angular.json /Users/shivammishra/angular.json.txt`. 
`mv` command will move the file to new location (`angular.json.txt`) and you can then delete.

Answer (score 0):

## Angular.js & Wrong Directions.

First of all, open a file called `angular.js` in the root folder.

And check if you add some wrong Directory. like the style or something like that. as example.

Suppose you add the bootstrap dependency and you want to add it to your project you will go to the angular.js and add it in the style configuration. so you will add it as the below:

```
 "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Check if you add double **dot** `..` not one dot in the path like the below:

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

Or you maybe add it in the following format:

```
"/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

or

```
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

### The correct format is :

```
 "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```