# Angular cli "invalid configuration" error on creating new app with CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a new application using angular CLI. I keep getting the "invalid configuration" error. I get the same error when I use the `ng --version` command.

```
$ ng new angular_organicstore
An invalid configuration file was found 
['/Users/USERNAME/.angular.json']. Please delete the file before 
running the command.
```

Node version: 10.14.1

Any ideas on how can I fix this error ? Much appreciated.

Comment: Hello! There seem to be a good number of question related to this out there
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53460171/10747134

Comment: it is prompting you to delete the file on that path have you tried doing so and re running command?

Comment: I tried searching for the .angular/json file in my username folder. But the file is not there.

Comment: fyi usually files that start with a period won't be shown in the file explorer/finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hve to delete your `.angular.json` file.

If you are on Windows, open `cmd` command prompt and do:

```
del Users\<USERNAME>\.angular.json
```

With shell `bash`:

```
rm Users/<USERNAME>/.angular.json
```