# Creating new project using Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli

I have an Angular 9 project inside of the following structure: d:\folder1\folder2. I am trying creating another project in d:\folder1\folder3. I am opening PowerShell in folder3 and using the following command:

```
ng new new-project
```

after saying no to router and selecting css I am getting this:

```
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"Trending_HIghCharts","version":"7.3.9","routing":false,"style":"css"}
Errors:

  Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector".
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Try using treding-highcharts or trending-high-charts for the project name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690584/8006943